# Generic method to manipulate *all* items in a list while handling exceptions

Tags: java, exception, lambda

I try to perform a method on all items of a list, while ignoring the entries that cause exceptions. If an exception is thrown, that item is ignored, and the following item is handled. At the end, the first exception that was encountered is thrown to alert that something went wrong.

Basically, this should result in the same output, independent of the order of inputs (if the exception is thrown by the first or last element, all other elements are still handled).

The specific case is:

```
List<Input> inputs = getInputs();
List<Output> outputs = new ArrayList<>();
MyException exc = null;

for(Input input: inputs){
    try{
        outputs.add(handleInput(input));
    } catch(MyException e) {
        if(exc != null){
            exc = e;
        }
    }
}

if(exc != null){
    throw exc;
}
```

A possible generic case doesn't compile:

```
public <I, O, E extends Exception> List<O> tryAll(List<I> inputs, ExceptionFunction<I, O, E> f) throws E {
    E exc = null;

    List<O> outputs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(I input: inputs){
        try{
            outputs.add(f.apply(input));
        } catch(E e){ //compile error
            if(exc != null){
                exc = e;
            }
        }
    }

    if(exc != null){
        throw exc;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Where `ExceptionFunction` is:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ExceptionFunction<T, R, E extends Throwable> {

    public R apply(T t) throws E;

}
```

The above code does not work since you cannot catch generic exceptions in Java. Is there another way to achieve this goal?

I realize that throwing the exception stops any access to the output list, but `handleInput` can mutate other flags, for which it is important that all elements are checked.

Comment: That's because you cannot catch a type parameter. In the ``catch`` block you must have a specific class.

Comment: @SchiduLuca Indeed that's why my proposed solution doesn't work. I was wondering if there's another way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Why you can't just catch all the exceptions `catch(Exception e)`? You can wrap it then to your own Exception and throw it at the end if you really need to have a specific throw declaration in your method, or...catch all and then make use of `instance of` although it slow you need to apply it only once

Comment: @Paizo Unfortunately instanceof doesnt work either with generic types. (e instanceof E) doed not compile either. I dont know what you mean with wrap it to your own Exception, do you have some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to solve this problem is to make `tryAll` take a type token that indicates the type of exception:

```
public <I, O, E extends Exception> tryAll(
    List<I> inputs,
    ExceptionFunction<I, O, E> function,
    Class<E> exceptionType)
        throws E;
```

Then in the implementation, just catch a broader type (e.g. `Exception`) and use `throw exceptionType.cast(ex)` to ensure that you only re-throw exceptions of the given type. A utility like Guava's [`Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf()`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ThrowablesExplained#propagation) can be useful here.

(Note that this is type safe because types that extend from `Throwable` can't be generic, so the exception type will always be reifiable.)

If you can shoehorn all the exceptions into a common hierarchy (or accept just dealing with a base type like `Exception`), then you can eliminate the `E` type parameter and the corresponding type token argument.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle it would be to change the design and do not use generic exception, instead use your own exception (for example `IgnorableException` instead of `E extends Throwable`).

In the case you described, it will be possible to achieve, you just will be forced to use exceptions derived from `IgnorableException` in your `handleInput` methods and in catch clause.